# Permission denied while moving a file to other directory in cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin

I am moving a file newp from Directory `Lenovo` to `Users` it says permission denied in cygwin.

```
 Lenovo@Aditya /cygdrive/c/Users/Lenovo
    $ mv newp ../
    mv: cannot move 'newp' to '../newp': Permission denied
```

How do I change the permission?

Comment: `/cygdrive/c/Users` is a special directory on Windows. You can not put something if you are not using an  Administrator

Comment: Okay, then How do I use administrator in order to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to make this work:

1.)Generate the SSH keys from `ssh-keygen`.

2.)Enter to the remote server and in that create a folder named `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

3.)Copy paste the key in the remote server's `authorized_key` folder.

4.)Run command  `rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress hello.txt ec2-user@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/home/ec2-user`

**Note**: hello.txt is a file that is created, which is to transfer to remote server.

Follow  [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh) link here to get the more idea.